# How to remove firefox mozilla grey icon in url?

Tags: https

I'm working on https://greenlabelroasters.com/. I just have make htaccess changes to redirect the site on https connection. Now site shows grey shield icon on url in firefox. How I can remove it?

Answer (score 1):

If you click on it, you will get a dialog that explains it is a security warning because you are loading insecure content into your otherwise secure page.

Don't do that and the warning will go away.

Comment: so how I can change it?

Comment: You find all the places where you load content over http instead of https and either remove them of change them to use https.

Comment: Files. Database. Wherever you store or construct URLs.

Comment: I have no idea what the server side code you haven't shared with us is doing with a particular (unspecified) bit of data you've changed.

Comment: FYI I'm using opencart.

Comment: By the way, How much time it will take to green the icon after changing the path in code and database?

Comment: The icon will change as soon as you reload the page and the browser doesn't detect a security problem with it.